# Webpack - Unable to find loader for SASS/SCSS

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I get the error message of:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/css/site.scss
Module parse failed: C:\_Code\vscode\angular2-webpack-starter\src\assets\css\site.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import "_variables.scss";
| @import "_helpers.scss";
| html {
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 5:0-34
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts


module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
        }, {
            test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"
        }, {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=application/octet-stream"
        }, {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "file"
        }, {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "url?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml"
        },{
            test: /\.sass$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        }
       ,{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        }], 
        rules:[...]
      //Other random code from webpack starter kit

};
```

The code below works correctly

```
//Works    
require("!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../assets/css/site.scss");
//Doesn't work
require('../assets/css/site.scss');
```

Already tried the following config options

```
{test: /\.scss$/,
loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]}

loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
loader: '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!'
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
```

I want to load from the webpack config, but doesn't seem to be working. The project is practically the entire of the Angular 2 webpack starter.

The correct packages are all installed as dependencies and I've read the tutorials and every solution I can find on Google.

Comment: Did you define this in webpack,common.ts ? it should be there

Comment: Yes, it's in the webpack.common.js and I've tried also declaring it at the top of the common.js file with require ([each loader name]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using and it works :

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
```

and install

```
"style-loader
"to-string-loader
"sass-loader
"node-sass
"css-loader
```

Comment: Changing it to a rule - not a loader worked for me. So this is technically correct, however I didn't use 'to-string-loader' and kept using style loader.